# Print only regular expression match with sed command

Tags: regex, linux, sed, timezone

I'm writing to ask you help me with the following issue.

The output of "timedatectl" on my Debian system is:

```
Local time: Wed 2022-11-16 13:02:00 CET
           Universal time: Wed 2022-11-16 12:02:00 UTC
                 RTC time: Wed 2022-11-16 12:02:01
                Time zone: Europe/Rome (CET, +0100)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

How can I obtain only the "Europe/Rome" string, or obviously any other, using sed command?

I tried

`timedatectl | sed -ne 's/^ *Time zone: \([A-z0-9_\/]*\).*$/\1/p'`

but following message is returned:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 40: Invalid range end

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Use: `sed -n 's~^ *Time zone: \([A-Za-z0-9_/]*\).*$~\1~p'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bracket expression contains an `A-z` range that does not work with your current collation rules. If you add `LC_ALL=C` before `sed` command, it won't error out, but it will still make it a bad regex since `A-z` ASCII char range also [matches some non-letter symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926). It makes sense to replace `A-z0-9` with `[:alnum:]`.

So, you can either fix the regex and use `'s/^ *Time zone: \([[:alnum:]_\/]*\).*$/\1/p'` or just capture any non-whitespaces there instead:

```bash
sed -n 's/^ *Time zone: \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

*Details*:

- `-n` - suppresses default line output
- `^ *Time zone: \([^ ]*\).*` - finds a line that starts with zero or more spaces, then has `Time zone:`  string, then any zero or more chars other than space are captured into Group 1 (with `\([^ ]*\)`) and the rest of the line (with `.*`),
- `\1` - replaces the match with Group 1 value
- `p` - prints the result of the successful substitution

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/FH6UnO):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='Local time: Wed 2022-11-16 13:02:00 CET
           Universal time: Wed 2022-11-16 12:02:00 UTC
                 RTC time: Wed 2022-11-16 12:02:01
                Time zone: Europe/Rome (CET, +0100)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no'
sed -n 's/^ *Time zone: \([^ ]*\).*$/\1/p' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Europe/Rome
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the very clear explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En '/Time zone/s~[^/]* ([^ ]*).*~\1~p' input_file
Europe/Rome
```